A second order ordinary differential equation problem
I am trying to solve this problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $F \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function such that $F(1) = 0$. Let $y \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function such that $y'' + F(y) = 0$. Show that if there exists a $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y(t_0) = 1$ and $y'(t_0) = 0$, then $y(t) = 1$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
I don't even know where to start with this problem. It is an IVP, but I do not what to do. At some point I guess I should get that $y'(t) = 0$ and integrating and evaluating, I would get $y(t) = 1$. But I don't know how to get there. Does anybody have any hints? Any help is appreciated.
EDIT: Following the suggestions given, I have made some progress, but I don't think I'm done.
Let $y' = z$ and let $G(y,z) = (z,-F(y))$. Then we can write
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} y\\
z \end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix}z \\ -F(y) \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
with $y(t_0) = 1$ and $z(t_0) = 1$. Since $y$ is $C^2$, $z$ is $C^1$ and thus $G$ is locally Lipschitz. This means that by the Picard-Lindelof theorem this IVP has a unique solution, say$\begin{pmatrix} u(t)\\ w(t)\end{pmatrix}$. Now, we can also see that $y(t) = 1$ is a solution that forces $F \equiv 0$ since $y' = y'' = 0$. Thus, the unique solution to the problem must be $y(t) = 1$.
There are two things that I still don't get. The first one is how specific $F$ turned out to be. But I guess it was forced by the Picard-Lindelof theorem. The second one is that the problem requires that solution to be valid for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The theorem only gives me a solution valid for an interval that contains $t_0$. Can I say it is valid for all $\mathbb{R}$?

Use an appropriate existence and uniqueness theorem to show that the IVP $u''+F(u)=0$ with $u(t_0)=1$ and $u'(t_0)=0$ has an unique solution (e.g. the Picard-Lindelöf theorem in vector form will do the work). Then show that $u=1$ is a solution, so by uniqueness $y=1$.

@Albert Thanks for the reply. I have some questions. Why do I have to work with $u$? Can't I just apply the theorem to $y$? Also, won't I have to assume that $F(y) = 0$ when showing that $y(t) = 1$ is a solution? All the required numerical conditions would be satisfied, but it seems too specific since I know nothing about $F$.

You know that $F(1)=0$.
